# pagespeed in cpanel failing with certain domains

Tags: cpanel, cdn, pagespeed

My host has a cpanel which allows turning on the pagespeed from google. However turning it on produces 403 error for exteranally hosted js libraries on some domains( cdnjs maxcdn in my case) but not with googleapis. Any reason for the same?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, open your .htaccess file you will find this somewhere in the file :

```
# mod_pagespeed configuration - Do NOT modify the contents
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeedDomain *
    ModPagespeed on
</IfModule>
# End of mod_pagespeed configuration- Do NOT modify the contents
```

Replace this with :

```
# mod_pagespeed configuration - Do NOT modify the contents
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeedDomain http://yourdomain.com
    ModPagespeed on
</IfModule>
# End of mod_pagespeed configuration- Do NOT modify the contents
```